# Laravel where clause on object?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 million rows in my database which I need to filter with time, as you all can guess the problem is about speed.

I am currently using the `remember` function to cache my queries. But I have some exact queries which my user are allowed so select. What i mean by this is:

- All data of the last year
- All data of the 6 months
- All data of the last month
- All data of the last week

Which means I have 4 queries to cache... All of them take about 30 seconds to be taken if you run the query without cache.

The thing I want is do is to filter that data after I receive all data *once* and cache it.

So that I can use the **all data** to filter how I want.

A bit more clearly with some code:

```
<?php

if (Cache::has('alldata')) {
    $alldata = Cache::get('alldata');
} else {
    $alldata = Data::all();
}

// Filters
$alldata->where('activity', '=', 1)->get();

// The code i currently use for every filter
$lastYearData = Data::where('column', '=', 'filter')->get();
// The line above "4 times" for each filter

?>
```

Comment: You probably don't want to store millions of rows in cache...

Comment: I suppose the table contains millions rows but the result, just few of them.

Comment: You can add a filter on Before and After and this way you can Cache the output to a file, and this way you'll server a static file content next time until some changes are made on DataBase.

Answer (score 1):

The where() method will call SQL where function. You cannot use it after get result. So you must filter with PHP :

```
$lastYearData = array_filter($alldata, function ($value) {
    return $value['date']->diffInDays() <= 365;
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but it should be noted that it'd be **much** more performant to do this in the SQL when you're talking about millions of rows. This will have to go through each one line by line.

Comment: It's not because the table contains millions rows that the result contains as much as it. By example, if there are 10 000 activity numbers.

Comment: Yes, but the OP shows that they're caching `Data::all();` which will be all 4M rows.

Comment: Oh dawn yes, hope the all method have been overrided.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'cache' on PHP will not work since it will be cleared once PHP is done handling the request.

With proper table indexes, your query should not take that much time.
Also, MySQL does caching so you don't really have to implement caching on PHP side unless your query's WHERE condition change a lot.

Try to run your 30 second query on MySQL commandline twice in a row. You'll notice that the second run will return faster than the first run.